# Put numbers in Ascending order then label them (highest to lowest) 1,2,3 etc in next cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a small list of numbers in no particular order in a column

900
465
650
1125
800
1212
545

in the cell next to each I want to show were each number comes in ascending order 1,2,3 etc (highest to lowest)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in `A2:A8` then use the following

```
=HSTACK(SORT(A2:A8),SEQUENCE(7))
```

---

Or, else first sort the data and use `RANK()` function to label or simply enter one in first cell and use fill down to series fill.

`=RANK(A2,A2:A8,1)`

---

If you use the following then it will show in ascending order and labelled in highest to lowest order.

`=HSTACK(SORT(A2:A8),SEQUENCE(7,,7,-1))`

Or,

Using `RANK()` function first sort data in ascending order and then use

`=RANK(A2,A2:A8)`

---

In the `RANK()` function if the order is omitted it takes by default descending order and `1` is for ascending order.